# Laravel use multiple subdomains in one app

Tags: laravel, routes

My question can we use something like this in laravel routing like one routes for admin.domain.com and other routes for clients.domain.com. How achieve this in laravel routing.

For example:

```
// these needs to go clients.domain.com/route
Route::get('/clients', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index')->name('clients');
Route::get('/clients/order', 'App\Http\Controllers\KuponaiController@pridetiKupona')->name('clients.order');
//this one to admin.domain.com/admin
Route::get('/admin', 'App\Http\Controllers\KuponaiController@patvirtinimokodas')->name('dashboard');
```

Comment: please go through doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a route group and pass an array with a `domain` property:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'clients.domain.com'], function()
{
    // clients.domain.com/clients
    Route::get('/clients', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index')->name('clients');
    // clients.domain.com/clients/order
    Route::get('/clients/order', 'App\Http\Controllers\KuponaiController@pridetiKupona')->name('clients.order');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.domain.com'], function()
{
    // admin.domain.com/admin
    Route::get('/admin', 'App\Http\Controllers\KuponaiController@patvirtinimokodas')->name('dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There is clear documentation on how you can use subdomains in your Laravel application here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing.

```php
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

For this to work, you need to have this subdomain before registering root domain routes

Comment: Can I have another layer after Route::domain and before Route::get where I check if _{account}_ actually exists and if so, pass the User model down the line? If not, return 404